# "@inject"-ed attribute remains null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, java-ee-6, javabeans

I am trying to inject a service into my bean but it is always `null`.
I get the following error: WELD-001000 Error resolving property userBean against base null.

Some code snippets:

***index.xhtml***

```
<h:body>
    Hello from Facelets
    #{userBean.name}
</h:body>
```

***userbean.java***

```
package beans;

import Domain.User;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import service.UserService;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable{
    @Inject UserService service;
    private User user;

    public UserBean(){
        this.user = service.find_user("foo");
    }

    public String getName(){
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

***UserService.java***

```
package service;

import Domain.User;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@Stateless
public class UserService {
    public UserService(){}

    public User find_user(String name){
        return new User();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message *could* be a hint, that the JVM wasn't able to create an instance of `UserBean`. The following is some guessing and would have to be proven:

Dependecy Injection requires a dependency injector, a tool that *injects* an instance of `UserService` into a `UserBean`. In your code you're already using this injected instance during instantiation of the bean: you call the injected service in the constructor.

*If* the dependency injector starts it's work *after* the bean is created, *then* the call to the service inside the constructor will raise a `NullPointerException` (because `service` is still `null` at that time). It's worth checking that by trying to catch NPEs in the `UserBean` constructor for a moment. If you catch one - voilà - the dependency injector starts runnning after the bean has been created and, as a consequence, we can't use injected services during class instantiation (= in the constructor)

---

Workaround idea: implement a small service provider helper class - inner class could work:

```
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
    static class UserServiceProvider {
      @Inject static UserService service;
    }

    // ... 

    public UserBean() {
      this.user = UserServiceProvider.service.findUser("kaas"); 
    }

    // ...
}
```

Untested but could work - the service should be injected in the provider class *before* you use it in the beans constructor.

Comment: That seems to be the case, how would i fix this?

Comment: @Martijn v E by specification dependency injection happens AFTER the constructor.

Comment: Just curious, is there a way to know when dependency injector  starts working?

Answer (score 9):

Another alternative is use @PostConstruct method annotation.

```
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
    @Inject UserService service;
    private User user;
    public UserBean() {

    }

   @PostConstruct
    void init(){
        this.user = service.findUser("kaas"); 
    }

  }
```

Read [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html)